# How to set a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [LicensePlate]
      ,[Manufacturer]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Colour]
      ,[Year]
      ,[EngineSize]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [Cars2].[dbo].[Cartable1]
```

Above is my layout for a cars table. I am completely new to SQL and was wondering how I would set 'Licence Plate' as the primary key?

Comment: So what have you tried? That is a SELECT query, which is a DML (data manipulation language) statement.  Setting a primary key requires the use of a DDL (data definition language) statement.  Also, are you using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?  There are some shortcuts and GUI options you can use in there.

Comment: `Right Click` your table in `object explorer`, context menu will show `Design` Click it. It will show you table design, Now you can either right click a column and select `Set Primary Key` or select your column and find key icon from toolbar. Click It. Look below for Column Properties while primary column is selected, Click on drop down `Identity Specification` It will show two rows with `No` Double click on second one, both will change to Yes now save by `Ctrl+S`, if it gives error then you need to find Tools> Options > Designer: Uncheck `Prevent saving...` Click Ok and then Save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find any duplicates by that column.

```
SELECT
    C.LicensePlate,
    AmountDuplicates = COUNT(*)
FROM
    Cars2.dbo.Cartable1 AS C
GROUP BY
    C.LicensePlate
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

If any record shows up, you need to either delete all the duplicates or update their license plates so they don't repeat anymore.

You will also need to check for `NULL` values and update or delete them (primary key can't be null).

```
SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    Cars2.dbo.Cartable1 AS C
WHERE
    C.LicensePlate IS NULL
```

Then you can add the PRIMARY KEY constraint with:

```
ALTER TABLE Cars2.dbo.Cartable1 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Cartable1 -- Name of the constraint
    PRIMARY KEY (LicensePlate)
```

You might get an error if `LicensePlate` can hold `NULL` values. You can change it with an `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE Cars2.dbo.Cartable1 ALTER COLUMN LicensePlate VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL -- The proper data type
```

---

If you already have a primary key defined on that table you will have to drop it and then create your new one (one table can only have 1 primary key constraint at a time). You can check which one is it with the following query:

```
USE Cars2; -- The database name here

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Cartable1'
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'

SELECT 
    ColumnName = Col.Column_Name,
    ConstraintName = tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS Tab
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS Col ON
        Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND 
        Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
WHERE 
    Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND 
    Col.Table_Name = @TableName AND
    Col.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
```

Once you see the result, you can drop the current primary key with another `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE Cars2.dbo.Cartable1 DROP CONSTRAINT ConstraintNameFromThePreviousQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But now i get this error:

Msg 1779, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Table 'Cartable1' already has a primary key defined on it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to check for current primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for this EzLo

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE Cartable1(
    LicensePlate int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Manufacturer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Model varchar(255),
    Colour varchar(255),
    Model varchar(255),
    Year int,
    EngineSize int,
    Value float
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this when you create a table or through an `alter table` statement:

```
create table [Cars2].[dbo].[Cartable1] (
    LicensePlace varchar(?) primary key,
    . . . 
);
```

I recommend adding the primary key when you create the table and before you add any data into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
If You already have table with data try this ,


 ALTER TABLE [Cars2].[dbo].[Cartable1]
        ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_LicensePlate PRIMARY KEY(LicensePlate)
```